# Kendo API doc: configuration is not current object interface

Tags: telerik

I'm using Kendo UI v2015.2.624 and Telerik ASP.NET MVC VSExtensions 2015.3.622.0 and it has `$("#myGridId").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter` equals to some `function(e){...}` that adds a filter to collection.

But accordingly to [datasource doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter) it should be either Array or Object. So the documentation does not match API.

Where can I find up to date documentation for Kendo UI?

Comment: I would avoid mixing and matching Kendo versions it can have some interesting effects as you are experiencing. I would suggest upgrading to the latest version `2015.2.902` the latest documentation is the online version only that you are linking too and that will refer to the latest public build of kendo both `javascript` and `MVC wrappers`

Comment: It is outdated doc. See [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/uJOqU) Dojo. The latest [Kendo UI Q2 2015 SP2](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history) release. And it prints the function.

Comment: The filter will return an object if it has been assigned a filter see updated dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/uJOqU/3

Comment: Not sure I understand. That actually does not prove the doc correctness. As the doc points out only Array or Object. No notes about invoking this before usage.

Comment: Well when you run dataSource.filter what are you expecting to happen? If no filter is present then it will just return the function as no filter(s) exist. If there are filters then invoking the function will then return the array or filter object depending on how many filters you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears that Kendo doc at http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/introduction should be up to date. The thing that I took wrongly was that the configuration is not an API of initialized object, the datasource of the grid. And datasource actually has `filter` method. See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter .

(Duplicate at https://github.com/telerik/kendo-docs/issues/641#issuecomment-142629600)